# How can I know in which IClasspathEntry an IJavaElement belongs to?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have an `IJavaElement` and I wish to know which one of the `IClasspathEntry`s of an `IJavaProject` the element belongs to.

I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious, but I just couldn't find a simple solution to that.

Thanks in advance for any forthcoming tips and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
IPackageFragmentRoot root = (IPackageFragmentRoot) element.getAncestor(IJavaElement.PACKAGE_FRAGMENT_ROOT);
IClasspathEntry entry = root.getRawClasspathEntry();
```

Note, that this is not a one-to-one relation between a Java element and class-path entry, this code only returns the first entry.

Comment: Only checking for the first entry is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I guess I will just have get all the entries and iterate over them searching for a match.
Thanks for you reply.